# Passing values to input through g:each iteration

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

Say if i have this data from my controller that i want to pass it to my GSP

```
def test = [value: ['TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3']]
```

And in my GSP, i have the following

```
<g:set var="counter" value="${0}"/>
<g:set var="count" value="${count}"/>
<g:while test="${counter < count}">
    <g:set var="counter" value="${counter+1}"/>
    <g:each var='obj' in='${test}' status='i'>
        <g:textField id='justATest1' name='justATest' value='obj.value'>
        <g:textField id='justATest2' name='justATest' value='obj.value'>
        <g:textField id='justATest3' name='justATest' value='obj.value'>
    </g:each>
</g:while>
```

And i want it so that justATest1 will get TEST1,  justATest2 will get TEST2 and  justATest3 will get TEST3.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your model contains the following

```
def myAction() {
    [value: ['TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3']]
}
```

This should do it

```
<g:each status="i" in="${value}" var="item">
    <g:textField id="justATest${i}" name='justATest' value="${item}">
</g:each>
```

Comment: So i take it if say test = [value1:['val1_a','val1_b','val1_c'], value2:['val2_a','val2_b','val2_c']], i can use the value as ${item.value[i]}? Because in my controller i will pass object to the GSP.

Answer (score 0):

Ok seems i managed to iterate object in GSP

```
<g:each var='obj' in='${test}'>
    <g:each var='subObj' in='${obj.value}'>
        <p>${subObj}</p>
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```

But kind of not elegant enough.

I can do it too with this, as what Donal put in his answer

```
<g:each var='obj' in='${test.value}'>
    <p>${obj}</p>
</g:each>
```

But it would be hard i think if i want to iterate each item inside test object separately and uniquely.

Anyone please feel free to fix my approach.